# Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

How do I implement if the schedule has been expired where in I want to return a status of "Match will start soon".

here is the code:

```
 @if($match->schedule > 0)
      &nbsp;<strong id="match_schedule">Match will start soon</strong>
 @endif
```

I tried :

```
@if($match->schedule > $match->schedule)
      &nbsp;<strong id="match_schedule">Match will start soon</strong>
@endif
```

but it doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to compare a Carbon instance to int `0`. This causes the exception:

> Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int.

You can check if the schedule lies in the past by comparing it like this:

```
@if($match->schedule < Carbon\Carbon::now())
    &nbsp;<strong id="match_schedule">Match will start soon</strong>
@endif
```